# Value saving in local storage but not applying (Ionic - ngStorage)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I got this Ionic project and I have implemented an ion-slide-box now I want to track the page slider of the slide box and store it in local storage. I am using [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage).

I am able to track the current index of the slider and store it in local storage but when i refresh the page in browser the slider index starts back from the beginning. What am I doing wrong

Part of my controller code:

```
$scope.next = function () {
    // Then we make sure we update our index to the current slides index.
    $scope.ui.index = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex();
    console.log($scope.ui.index);
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.next();
    // Local storage
    $scope.localStorageSliderCurrentIndex = $scope.ui.index;
    $localStorage.localStorageSliderCurrentIndex = $scope.localStorageSliderCurrentIndex;
    console.log('The local storage value for current slider index is ',$localStorage.localStorageSliderCurrentIndex);

};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont see slidebox has a parameter for start slide index. But I see that ionicSlideBoxDelegate has 'set' method: slide(to, [speed])
So I think you can set first index at the start time as:

```
$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide($localStorage.localStorageSliderCurrentIndex);
```

Comment: slide has to be defined, as a scope?

Comment: No, as said, slide is a method of $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, call it:  $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide($localStorage.localStorageSliderCurrentIndex)

Comment: doing so will set the value to 0

Comment: $localStorage.localStorageSliderCurrentIndex = 0 at start time?

Comment: Are you sure you called to set first slide before your 'next' method run?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113303/discussion-between-vu-quyet-and-gy22).